# .draggable() is not working for no reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I was working on my project and had to use .draggable(). I wasn't able to make it work, I didn't know what's wrong so I decided to copy the exercise from Codeacademy and see if it would work. It didn't work either.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game Test</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='art.css' />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="stayaway"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
#stayaway {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:relative;
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#stayaway").draggable();

});
```

It is just a basic function. I don't know what's wrong here. Other functions like fadeOut are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is just fine . You just need to include the **jQuery-UI** files too

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#stayaway").draggable();

});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/b52c8pmk/)

You can download from **[here](https://jqueryui.com/download/all/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jquery-ui library:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game Test</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='art.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#stayaway {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:relative;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="stayaway"></div>

    </body>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#stayaway").draggable();

});
    </script>
</html>
```